# How do you launch system applications from within a Ubuntu Touch app?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Android had a concept of Intents by which you can launch the system apps using your own apps. Does Ubuntu touch have any options like that? If so how can one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From simple QML apps, you can't launch an external application (the Ubuntu SDK will probably support this feature in the future though).

To start a system application, your Touch application must be using some C++ code an then rely on [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html).

Regarding communication between apps, again using C++ you could use [QDBus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdbus-module.html).

Comment: Can you please explain me process of creating project of Qml Extension Library-Tabbed UI template. I was able to create a project but after creating project it asks to Run Cmake, if I hit run cmake it gives error:                                    CMake Error at backend/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    modules/dudeescape/backend.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx

Comment: I'd recommend reading this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/315560/ubuntu-sdk-has-no-c-examples), it provides a lot of links that will help you to start such application